# Trouble with webscraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to have the name of the hotel, usually I have no problem with this kind of scraping but here it doesn't work I don't understand.

Here's my script:

```
import numpy as np


import time
from random import randint
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
import random

#headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Referer': 'https://www.espncricinfo.com/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}

url = 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/fr/hyatt-regency-paris-etoile.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCA0oTUIMZWx5c2Vlc3VuaW9uSA1YBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAL_5ZqEBsACAdICJDcxYjgyZmI2LTFlYWQtNGZjOS04Y2U2LTkwNTQyZjI5OWY1YtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;hpos=1;no_rooms=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;srepoch=1619708145;srpvid=6f6268f8305e011d;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl'

results = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

hotel = soup.find('h2', class_ = 'hp__hotel-name').text

print(hotel)
```

Here's the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_booking_info_supp.py", line 75, in <module>
    hotel = soup.find('h2', class_ = 'hp__hotel-name').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I cannot understand why I obtained `None`, here's the html:

<sub>The link to the website is in the image</sub>

[image: html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out with `id` attribute from tag to get the text value

```
url = 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/fr/hyatt-regency-paris-etoile.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCA0oTUIMZWx5c2Vlc3VuaW9uSA1YBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAL_5ZqEBsACAdICJDcxYjgyZmI2LTFlYWQtNGZjOS04Y2U2LTkwNTQyZjI5OWY1YtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;hpos=1;no_rooms=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;srepoch=1619708145;srpvid=6f6268f8305e011d;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl'

results = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

hotel = soup.find("h2",attrs={"id":"hp_hotel_name"})

print(hotel.text.strip("\n").split("\n")[1])
```

Output:

```
'Hyatt Regency Paris Etoile'
```